# Как в Java сравнить два ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, arraylist

Как в Java сравнить два `new ArrayList<_People_>` на идентичность, пробую через contains - не работает, все время возвращает `false`.

Comment: Неплохо было бы увидеть как вы пробуете.

Comment: Полагаю, что у вас собственный класс `People`, в котором вы не переопределили метод `equals`

Comment: класс People мой,  "в котором вы не переопределили метод equals" можно по подробнее

Comment: @Suleymanovtat, Необходимо переопределение методов boolean equals(Object ob) и  int hashCode() , если логика приложения преду­сматривает использование элементов в коллекциях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People требуется реализовать функции equals. Вот мой пример

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //проверим работу equals
        if(new People(1, 2).equals(new People(1, 2))){ //МЫ ПОЛУЧИМ OK ЕСЛИ БУДЕТ ЧТО-ТО ТИПО ЭТОГО 1 2 1 2, ЕСЛИ 1 3 1 2 НЕ ОК
            System.out.println("OK");
        }else System.out.println("FALSE");


        ArrayList<People> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(new People(1, 2));
        arr.add(new People(2, 3));
        arr.add(new People(1, 2));

        ArrayList<People> arr2 = new ArrayList<>();
        arr2.add(new People(1, 2));
        arr2.add(new People(1, 2));
        arr2.add(new People(2, 3));


        if(arr.size() == arr2.size() && arr.containsAll(arr2)){
            System.out.println("OK"); //ДВА ARRAYLIST РАВНЫ:)
        }else System.out.println("FALSE");

    }


}

class People {
    private int i;
    private int m;
    public People(int i, int m){
        this.i = i;
        this.m = m;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){ //РЕАЛИЗУЕМ МЕТОД СРАВНЕНИЯ
        if(obj == this)return true; //ссылки идентичные, сравнение не требуется
        People people = (People) obj; //я сделаю без сравнения типов
        return people.i == i && people.m == m; //сравниваем внутренности(зависит от класса).
    }
}
```

Comment: было бы замечательно, если еще добавить override для hashCode() в данный пример

Answer (score -4):

Если используете Maven, можете воспользоваться утилитой [Java List Helpers](https://github.com/bicoco/java-list-helpers)
В README описан пример использования